# Код каких веб-фреймворков можно законно скачать в открытом доступе?

Tags: веб-программирование

Код каких веб-фреймворков можно законно скачать в открытом доступе?

Comment: @Alex9, практически всех. Большинство вообще распространяются в, кхм, некомпилированном виде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Github](https://github.com/) и вперед в поиск.